# Simulate rigid body hitting thick liquid. (How to slow an individual rigid body?)

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I’m trying to drop rigid bodies into a vat of slime. The rigid body needs to stop hard the moment it hits the surface of the slime, then slowly sink in.

I’ve tried using translation damping at the moment of impact, but I’m getting weird results where it doesn’t slow at all until it is set to 1, then it moves far too slowly.

I’ve also tried using a drag forcefield and animating that value at the right moments…but then my rigid body object just disappears.

I can’t find a solution that doesn’t seem to bug out, and I don’t want to hand animate it because it falls back out of the slime and continues on its path as a rigid body object.

Comment: did u try to animate a "normal" force field?